# Opencv: cvCaptureFromCAM returning NULL

Tags: c++, opencv, video, webcam

I'm in Linux Mint (don't know the version) and am using a Logitech Orbit AF webcam. I try the following code, but all I get is "ERROR: Capture is null!" Please help!!!!!

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Data Structure to store cam.
    CvCapture* cap=cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    //Image variable to store frame
    IplImage* frame;
    //Window to show livefeed
    cvNamedWindow("LiveFeed",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    if(!cap)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Capture is null!\n";
    }
    while(1)
    {
        //Load the next frame
        frame=cvQueryFrame(cap);
        //If frame is not loaded break from the loop
        if(!frame)
            break;
        //Show the present frame
        cvShowImage("LiveFeed",frame);
        //Escape Sequence
        char c=cvWaitKey(33);
        //If the key pressed by user is Esc(ASCII is 27) then break out of the loop
        if(c==27)
           break;
    }
    //CleanUp
    cvReleaseCapture(&cap);
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this call returns `NULL`:

```
CvCapture* cap = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
if (!cap)
{
    // print error and exit
    cout << "ERROR: Capture is null!\n";
    return -1;
}
```

it means that no device was found at index `0`. Try passing `CV_CAP_ANY` instead to let OpenCV select a valid index number for you.

If that doesn't work, it may be that your camera is not supported by OpenCV. Try to find it in [this list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS).

Comment: Fixed my problem. Just didn't have Qt installed

Comment: Were you trying this on Windows? It sucks not being able to see missing dependencies at runtime.

Comment: Well, then it should have screamed at your face. Any chance you missed it?

Comment: I might have... but it works now... which is what's important!

Comment: No. But depending on how you compiled OpenCV on your platform you might need FFmpeg or GStreamer libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the latest version of opencv didn't work for me (2.4.9). I installed 2.3 and it magically works now.